# How to extract a single value from a JSON object with a single "key-value"?

Tags: json, haskell

An Http server returns data in this JSON format:

```
{
    some_value: "fdsafsafdsafs"
}
```

Object with single key and value.

I want to parse a returned data in that format and I've not been able to. I don't want to create a special data for that.
Instead I want to parse or deconstract/pattern match it and get the value of "some_value"

Code:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Aeson as Aeson


func1 :: IO (Either MyError BS.ByteString)
func1 = do
  resp <- sendRequestAndReturnJsonBody
  -- [.........]
```

I've tried:

1)

```
case Aeson.decode resp of
  Just (Aeson.Object obj) -> -- how to exctract "some_value" from "obj" now?
  _ -> _
```

2)

```
let (Aeson.Object ("some_value", String s)) = resp
-- [......]
```

3)

```
case resp of
  (Object obj) -> 
    case (lookup "some_value" obj) of
      Just (String s) -> pure $ Right s
      _ -> undefined
```

All the attemps are wrong.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely in your third attempt, you did not use the `lookup` of the **`Data.HashMap.Strict`** module from the [**`unordered-containers`** package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers). You furthermore should enable the `OverloadedStrings` option to make use of string literals that have a `Text` type. You thus can implement this as:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HM
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Aeson as Aeson


func1 :: IO (Either MyError BS.ByteString)
func1 = do
  resp <- sendRequestAndReturnJsonBody
  case Aeson.decode resp of
      Just (Aeson.Object obj) -> case (HM.lookup "some_value" obj) of
          Just (Aeson.String s) -> pure (Right s)
          _ -> undefined
      _ -> undefined
```

If we construct a function:

```
f :: Applicative f => ByteString -> f (Either a Text)
f resp = case Aeson.decode resp of
      Just (Aeson.Object obj) -> case (HM.lookup "some_value" obj) of
          Just (Aeson.String s) -> pure (Right s)
          _ -> undefined
      _ -> undefined
```

It has a type that given `resp` is a `ByteString`, it will return an `Applicative f => f (Either a Text)`, hence if in your case `resp` is indeed a `Value`, it can return an `IO (Either MyError)`.

For objects that contain *one* element, we can use the [**`OverloadedLists`**](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/overloaded-lists) extension, and thus make use of that to pattern match on a list pattern for that `HashMap`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists, OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Aeson as Aeson


func1 :: IO (Either MyError BS.ByteString)
func1 = do
  resp <- sendRequestAndReturnJsonBody
  case Aeson.decode resp of
      Just (Aeson.Object [("some_value", Aeson.String s)]) -> pure (Right s)
      _ -> undefined
```

For more items, this will not match. Trying this for more items can fail, since the order of the items with `toList` is unspecified, and thus can depend on implementation details.

Comment: is it possible to do something similar to this `let (Object ("some_value", String s)) = resp`. I've tried, it didn't compile

Comment: @Rubashka351: well that would be strange, since an `Object` is wrapping a `HashMap`. You can, for singleton objects, make use of the `OverloadedLists` extension.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you said you didn't want to create a custom data type, this is still the most straightforward way of getting the `let some_pattern = result` syntax that you want.  Note that you don't need to use the data type for anything other than parsing.  Think of it as the "usual" Aeson method for creating a new pattern that you can match the result on.

You can either use generics to define the data type or write a custom `FromJSON` instance to avoid cluttering your namespace with a `some_value` field:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Data.Aeson

newtype SomeValue = SomeValue String
instance FromJSON SomeValue where
  parseJSON = withObject "SomeValue" $ \o -> SomeValue <$> o .: "some_value"

myjson :: ByteString
myjson = "{ \"some_value\": \"fdsafsafdsafs\" }"

main = do
  case decodeStrict myjson of
    Just (SomeValue v) -> print v
    _ -> error "didn't work!"
```